# JPQL Query is returning a Vector instead a List

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

For some reason a JPQL Query is returning a Vector instead a List, so when this Vector reach the webApplication I get a List of empty objects.

This is my model class:

```
package model.logs;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "logs")
@XmlRootElement
public class Log implements Serializable {


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_firmado_log")
    private BigInteger idLog;

    @Column(name = "fecha_log")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar fechaLog;

    @Column(name = "codigo_resultado")
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private Integer codigoResultado;

    @Column(name = "mensaje")
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private String mensaje;

    @Column(name = "fecha_log_fin")
    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar fechaLogFin;

    public PadeLog() {
    }



    public BigInteger getIdPadeLog() {
        return idPadeLog;
    }

    public void setIdPadeLog(BigInteger idPadeLog) {
        this.idPadeLog = idPadeLog;
    }

    public Calendar getFechaLog() {
        return fechaLog;
    }

    public void setFechaLog(Calendar fechaLog) {
        this.fechaLog = fechaLog;
    }

    public Integer getCodigoResultado() {
        return codigoResultado;
    }

    public void setCodigoResultado(Integer codigoResultado) {
        this.codigoResultado = codigoResultado;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }
    public Calendar getFechaLogFin() {
        return fechaLogFin;
    }

    public void setFechaLogFin(Calendar fechaLogFin) {
        this.fechaLogFin = fechaLogFin;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to get my list:

```
@Override
    public List<Log> findAll() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Log as l",Log.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

And this is what I'm getting ... a list of objects with every attribute set to `null` (cropped to avoid problems).

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: not a duplicated since this is a plain object without relationships

Comment: can you try changing your query like this please? ` Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Log l ", Log.class);`  and let me know?

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your comment but I got the same result

Comment: A Vector IS a List, so you might want to explain your problem more and change the header.  How are you inserting Log instances in the database?   How are you determining the entities are filled with null values - are they proxy Entities?

Comment: Hi! yes, I just remember that I used to get a List object some time ago and was weird, and in the other hand the information was being lost when  I tried to read from another Bean.  I've checked another post that recommended to disable the Eclipse Link Weaving, I'm not sure of the impact of this but it seems to work